# Proof that $ \frac{ln{x}}{(x^3-1)} <\frac{x}{x^3} , \forall x \in[2,\infty) $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$ \frac{ln{x}}{(x^3-1)} <\frac{x}{x^3} , \forall x \in[2,\infty) $$

This is specifically for an improper integral question, where the left term needs to be proven convergent or divergent for the interval $$ [2,\infty) $$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you write $\dfrac x {x^3}$ instead of $\dfrac 1 {x^2}$?

Comment: It can be simplified as such, however I left it in the simplified form to show that $x>\ln{x}$, but since $x^3>x^3-1$, the denominator should normally be smaller to apply comparison theorem, but I know that the entire phrase is larger despite the larger denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

$$\ln(x)<x-1$$

$$x^2+x+1>x^2$$

(the last one for $x\ge2$)

Comment: Thanks! I tried rewriting as a difference of cubes, but it didn't occur to me that x-1 would still be greater than lnx.

Comment: Maybe you know $\ln(1+y)<y$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=\ln x-x+\frac{1}{x^2} \Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1-\frac{2}{x^3}<0, ~\mbox{for}~x\ge 1. $$ So $f(x)$ is decreasing function on $[1,\infty].$ This means that
$f(x) \le f(1) \Rightarrow f(x) \le 0$. Rearrangin this we get 
$$\frac{\ln x}{x^3-1} \le \frac{x}{x^3},~~ x > 1.$$